# Rails no route matches PUT, but rake route shows it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, request

I'm trying to implement a page where I can add a quantity to a product in a cart. Any good tutorials on this?

So I tried implementing the typical `edit` form with the `form_for` but that kept giving me errors like this...

```
<%= form_for(@cart[0]) do |f| %>
  <% if @cart.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@cart.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this cart from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @cart.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And the error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"carts", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

...keep in mind this is in the `edit` action, so I don't know why it is complaining about the `show` action. Anyways I have made `id: false` and customized my primary key to `cart_id`

In the `index.html` file I customize parameters

```
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_cart_path(cart, :id => cart.cart_id, :product_id => cart.product_id) %></td>
```

This is what I have in the controller action

```
  def edit
    @cart = Cart.where(:cart_id => params[:id], :product_id => params[:product_id])
  end
```

And I have confirmed it finds the correct record.

So, I said screw all of this and decided to just make a `form_tag` and then send the quantity as a parameter to the `update` action. Like the following in `edit.html`

```
<%= form_tag('/carts', method: 'put') do %>
  <%= number_field_tag "Quantity" %>
<% end %>
```

But then it complains there is no put route, when there is...

```
    cart GET    /carts/:id(.:format)         carts#show
         PATCH  /carts/:id(.:format)         carts#update
         PUT    /carts/:id(.:format)         carts#update
```

I would imagine this error is there because I don't have an `:id` so then I decided to override the put action like the following

```
  resources :carts, :except => 'put' do
    # put :carts
    put "/carts" => "carts#update"
  end
```

But I get the same `no put route found` error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Lets focus on the initial error In which line of the code did you get this error `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"carts", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]`?

Answer (score 1):

Both of these routes:

```
PATCH  /carts/:id(.:format)         carts#update
PUT    /carts/:id(.:format)         carts#update
```

require an id. The id will be the id of the cart you want to update. Something like `cart_path(@cart.id)` would work **or** if you want to use that string, you'll need to pass it the id `"/carts/#{@cart.id}"`

Comment: Please don't build paths or urls by string concatenation or string interpolation. It is lead to errors that are hard to find when you change routes or refactor your app. To use the url helper is much better, because it at least ensures that the url really exists.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the existing entry from your routes file for carts.  I'm guessing that you might have something like this in your routes file already:

`resources :carts`

Which would be find if the user had more than one shopping cart...  but that's not generally the case, is it?  You have one.  It's a singleton.  Thus, your route would be:

`resource :cart`

There's a few more things that look wrong in what you're showing, I can't cover it all, but here's a couple of tips:

I recommend using something like [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) to make the form and route generation easier.

You're fetching the cart by ID in your controller - do you want users to be able to modify each others carts?  Probably not - you probably want something along the lines of `@cart = current_user.cart`

... and, in fact, you're fetching it by cart ID and by... *product_id*?  Really?  Does a cart only have one product in it?  I would expect Cart to `has_and_belongs_to_many :products` and Product to `has_and_belongs_to_many :carts` - because many users might have the same product in their cart, and a cart could have many products in it.

that's a start - good luck!